# i face this problem when i use ajax in codignator

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://[::1]/pos/index.php/Sub_Category/get_sub_cat/3' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: When you get an error message, always start by google it. This has been asked and answered again and again all over the web.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet which shows how you produced the error?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example